# python code returning AttributeError: module 'xarray' has no attribute 'open_rasterio'

Tags: python, python-xarray

```
preds = Inference(model=model, normalizing_dict=None).run(p)

# Check size
assert preds.dims["lat"] == 17
assert preds.dims["lon"] == 17

# Check all predictions between 0 and 1
assert preds.min() >= 0
assert preds.max() <= 1

preds
```

I have this section of code that i am trying to use to train a random forest classifier, this section is about runninng inference.

The problem is I keep getting ther error: module 'xarray' has no attribute 'open_rasterio'

I have tried installing and importing rioxarray in a seperate cell on google colab but its still not working.

Am i missing something?

Comment: As `xarray.open_rasterio` was deprecated from version 0.20.0, it is recommended to replace it by `rioxarray.open_rasterio` according to rioxarray doc (https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/getting_started/getting_started.html#rioxarray).

Comment: where is the rest of the code ?  there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)